# Eloquent get all models associated with model X

Tags: php, mysql, database, eloquent

The problem I'm facing is that I want all matches belonging the to the player for a specific season. I'm using Eloquent in combination with Slim 2.

This is my ERD:

[image: Image of ERD]

Is this even possible? I was thinking of start with the season and that way I can go down but than I face the problem of the fact a match can have multiple players and I would love to use the player model to call all his matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier - when you have `season id`:

```
$player->matches()->whereHas('game', function ($q) use ($seasonId) {
  $q->where('season_id', $seasonId);
})->get();
```

A bit longer with just its name:

```
$player->matches()->whereHas('game.season', function ($q) use ($seasonName) {
  $q->where('name', $seasonName);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what is needed. I use it for retrieve multiple players with their matches from the database.